# How to login with a user with role userAdmin in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I have **mongod** server up and running as a service on ubuntu 14.04, i started **mongo** shell and created a user.

```
db.createUser(   {
    user: "testAdmin",
    pwd: "12345678",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdmin", db: "students" } ]  
} )
```

after that I changed edit the **mongod.conf** and set **auth=true** and restarted the **mongod** server as a service.

After all this, when I want to start the **mongo shell** with user **testAdmin** .

```
mongo -u testAdmin -p 12345678 --authenticationDatabase students
```

But I am not able to login and it is giving me error.

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:25018/test
2016-10-13T05:56:27.500+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:25018, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-10-13T05:56:27.500+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:25018, connection attempt failed :
```

First when I am specifying database **students** why it is trying to connect to **test**? Second I know that userAdmin role in mongodb is not for read/write in database with userAdmin I can only manage user roles. But to manage other users i still need to login in mongo shell.

It is working when I turn off the auth in mongod.conf, so other things are fine, only authentication is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> > First when I am specifying database students why it is trying to connect to test?

You are not specifying the database (students) you want to connect to here.

The `--authenticationDatabase` is used to specify the database where the user had been created and which is used for the authentication process.

You should also specify students as the db option you want to connect to. If you omit it, the shell automatically tries to connect to `test` database:

`mongo students -u testAdmin -p 12345678 --authenticationDatabase students`

Note the addition of `students` just after `mongo`.

This is assuming the user has been created in the `students` database (and not `admin` or other). Note that in that case the `db` declaration within `role` is redundant:

`roles: [ { role: "userAdmin", db: "students" } ]`

could have also been specified as:

`roles: [ "userAdmin" ]`